# Combining gridded polygons at state level within same shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a polygon .SHP containing a field of separate, gridded polygons, which comprise the US and its outliers. I need those separate polygons grouped by state in the same .SHP. I have tried several avenue to join this layer to a state boundary file to no avail.

Ideally I am looking for a manual process.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what output you want, screenshots would help.

Try:
[Intersect:](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm)

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or
>   portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature
>   classes will be written to the output feature class.

Or [spatial join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm):

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
>   relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the
>   join features are written to the output feature class.

Comment: There is no State_Name Field wihin the .shp.

Comment: The spatial join did not give the desired result the grid field does not correspond to a state FIPS code

Comment: @NicoleParsons you need to edit your question and provide more details about your inputs and desired output. Im voting to close your question.

Comment: I can upload a screen shot not sure how

Comment: Not sure that made it any better